# How to extract points from a graph?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, matplotlib

I have a question.

I have plotted a graph using Matplotlib like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy
from scipy.interpolate import spline

widths = numpy.array([0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180])
heights = numpy.array([26, 38.5, 59.5, 82.5, 120.5, 182.5, 319.5])

xnew = numpy.linspace(widths.min(),widths.max(),300)
heights_smooth = spline(widths,heights,xnew)

pyplot.plot(xnew,heights_smooth)
pyplot.show()
```

Now I want to query a height value using width value as an argument. I cannot seem to find how to do that. Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`plot()` returns a useful object: `[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x38c9910>]`
From that we can get x- and y-axis values:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np
...
line2d = plt.plot(xnew,heights_smooth)
xvalues = line2d[0].get_xdata()
yvalues = line2d[0].get_ydata()
```

Then we can get the index of one of the width values:

```
idx = np.where(xvalues==xvalues[-2]) # this is 179.3979933110368
# idx is a tuple of array(s) containing index where value was found
# in this case -> (array([298]),)
```

And the corresponding height:

```
yvalues[idx]
# -> array([ 315.53469])
```

To check we can use `get_xydata()`:

```
>>> xy = line2d[0].get_xydata()
>>> xy[-2]
array([ 179.39799331,  315.53469   ])
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I had to make only one minor adjustment to it: `idx=(numpy.abs(xvalues-<known_xvalue>)).argmin()`. After this, `yvalues[idx]` gives me what I want. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the array to a list:

```
>>> heights[list(widths).index(30)]
38.5
```

for the interpolated result:

```
s = xnew[56] 
print s, heights_smooth[list(xnew).index(s)]
33.7123745819, 40.9547542163
```

As `xnew` is an ordered list you could use the [bisect module](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) to find a closest width value for a queried width, and then find the corresponding height, in a similar fashion:

```
....
import bisect
pyplot.plot(xnew,heights_smooth)
#33.1222 is a queried value which does not exist in xnew.
index_of_nearest_width = bisect.bisect_left(xnew, 33.1222) 
width_val = xnew[index_of_closest_width]
print width_val, heights_smooth[list(xnew).index(width_val)]
#prints the nearest width to 33.1222 then the corresponding height.
33.7123745819 40.9547542163
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option if you're willing to use a different spline function:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy
from scipy import interpolate

widths = numpy.array([0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180])
heights = numpy.array([26, 38.5, 59.5, 82.5, 120.5, 182.5, 319.5])

xnew = numpy.linspace(widths.min(),widths.max(),300)
heights_smooth = interpolate.splrep(widths,heights) #Use splrep instead of spline

#Select desired width values
width_vals = [0, 80.5, 38.98743]   

#splev returns the value of your spline evaluated at the width values.    
heights = interpolate.splev(width_vals, heights_smooth)
```

Then

```
In[]:  heights
Out[]: array([ 26.        ,  74.1721985 ,  44.47929453])
```

Or evaluate at a point:

```
w = 167.2
heights = interpolate.splev(w, heights_smooth)
height = heights.item()

In[]:  height
Out[]: 247.8396196684303
```

The `.item()` function is necessary because `splev` returns an `array()`